# Different input value but my output does not change

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif

    int savings;
    cin >> savings;

    if (savings > 5000){
        cout << "kiara\n"; 
    }
    else  {
        cout << "ayushi\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My input and output:

[image]

This is an if-else condition where I have to put input and bring output out of it. When I am putting `3000` or `2000`, it is only showing `Kiara` instead of `ayushi`.

Comment: add debugging code ... print value of `savings`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get ayushi. I only removed the online judge part.

Comment: note that in the screen shot the input file you show is called 'intput.txt' but you are opening 'input.txt'

Comment: @Yunnosch "*I only removed the online judge part*" - which is, sadly, where the problem lies to begin with, which is why you aren't seeing it happen.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I suspected that and partly commented to provoke OP to think and double check. I did not spot the relevant info on the file name though, the risk of info in screenshots. I do like "intput" though, for its nicely symmetric file name lenght and the implicatio of numerical content... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your input file is named `intput.txt`, but your code is looking for `input.txt` instead.  This causes `cin >> savings` to fail, setting `savings` to an unspecified value (in my test, it is set to `32767`), and putting `cin` into an error state that you are not checking for.

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Zf7Uhjo6a)

Always validate input before using it, eg:

```
int savings;
if (cin >> savings) {
    if (savings > 5000) {
        cout << "kiara\n"; 
    }
    else {
        cout << "ayushi\n";
    }
}
else {
    // error ...
}
```